# How to split semicolon separated data to columns in hive and also transpose it?

Tags: hadoop, hive, transpose

I have a dataset in the following format in hive table.

```
<br><b>|Col_1&nbsp;| Col_2&nbsp; &nbsp;|Col_3</b></<br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;a;b;c;d&nbsp;&nbsp;|m;n</br>
<br>|abc_2  | e;f;d &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|l;h;p<br>
```

I need to convert the data into the following format.

```
<br><b>|Col_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;Col_2_OR_3&nbsp;|Value</b></<br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;a</br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;b</br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;c</br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;d</br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;m</br>
<br>|abc_1&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;n</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;e</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;f</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_2&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;d</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;l</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;h</br>
<br>|abc_2&nbsp;|&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Col_3&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;p</br>
```

The data initially is unique at values in **Col_1**.The semicolon separated values in **Col_2** and **Col_3** need to be separated and transposed as a new column **Value** and another column needs to be created **Col_2_OR_3** which has the values of column header for the column from which the semicolon separated value is picked from **Col_2** or **Col_3**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select col_1,'Col_2',col_2_al
from <table_name>
lateral view explode(split(col_2, "\\\;")) col_2_al as col_2_al 
union all
select col_1,'Col_3',col_2_al
from <table_name>
lateral view explode(split(col_3,"\\\;")) col_3_al as col_2_al
```